# Youtube analytics API content owner-based queries not returning data

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to get ad revenue data from the Youtube analytics API. It seems that no queries I make with `id=contentOwner==<CONTENT_OWNER_ID>` return data: I get a 200 response back with all the column name information, but no `rows` and no actual data. This occurs *even* for metrics like `comments`, which *does* return data when I use `id=channel==<CHANNEL_ID>` (i.e., `id=channel==<CHANNEL_ID>&metrics=comments&filters=video==<VIDEO_ID>` returns the number of comments for that video; `id=contentOwner==<CONTENT_OWNER_ID>&metrics=comments&filters=video==<VIDEO_ID>` does not.) The problem occurs both in my Python code and in the query explorer (https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query#try-it).

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a secret permissions issue, even though I'm getting a 200 back? Is it a bug?

Comment: 200 just means the connection was successful and a response what returned.  If it's empty than either there are no results, your query is incorrect. I'm guessing but I'm willing to bet you can't simply see how much videos you dont own are earning.

Comment: @Chris I see the same results even when the account owner performs the OAuth2 handshake in the query explorer...who would have the correct permissions?